# Init hash variable by pre-processor

Tags: hash, macros, c-preprocessor

I found this description about creating a hash of a string to a uint32_t size:
http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/20/cpp-constant-string-hash

I want to use this macro to init a global variable. I don't want to add the string in compiled binary, only the hash.

But when using this macros I get the error: `error:Initializer element is not constant`

Is there a work around for this is for C & GCC compiler?

Any other idea to place a hash of a string by pre-processor?

Answer (score 0):

In C, a static initializer must be a constant expression, and C is very picky about what a constant expression is:

> An *arithmetic constant expression* shall have arithmetic type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, and `_Alignof` expressions. (§6.6/8)

Note that string literals are not in the list of valid operands, so `"A string"[2]` does not qualify.

C++ does not require static initializers to be constant expressions, and it is also a lot more generous about what is accepted as a constant expression. (For example, a `static const int` variable can be used in C++, but not in C.)

So the C preprocessor is not going to be able to help you construct a static declaration initialized to a hash computed from a character string. If you really want to do this, your best bet is probably to do your own preprocessing of the source file, with a utility which identifies the calls to `HASH` and replaces them with the computed hash as an integer constant.